# InDesign: create template and paste from Word

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm asked to convert a Word document to an InDesign file for print.

The Word document only contains the text, but in InDesign I need to set up a template with paging and a logo on each page.
While I'm able to do this, I can't figure out a way to completely paste the text from the Word document in InDesign so that it will automatically create multiple pages for it.

So basically I just want to create the template in InDesign and then completely paste all the text from the Word document in it.
Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: press **Shift** when placing the text.

---

Heres a video about placing text ( The link is to the exact point where this is mentioned, though it might be beneficial to watch the whole thing. )

[Adobe TV - Getting Started: 06 Placing and flowing text](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-indesign-cs4/getting-started-06-placing-and-flowing-text/?t=269.131)

Comment: That helped a lot, but I've created my template without a textfield, when I use the Shift key when placing the text, the textfield in the newly created page is all wrong, is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @woutr_be It depends what you mean by "all wrong". It would help if you would show how you've laid out the text in your first page or spread and then show how the text is flowing into the newly created pages (Asuming that it should match). Though first thought that comes to mind is that you haven't properly set columns in your document (Top menu: Layout > Margin and columns. There you can adjust columns. Text will flow within the column areas).

Comment: Thank, I already solved it by just pasting the entire text in one text area and then pressing the red "+", this allows me to drag another textfield. Might be a more difficult way, but this works fine for now

Comment: @woutr_be Ah, so the problem wasn't really how the text was flowing into the new pages, but rather how to do that? The video linked in my answer also covers this as the first thing after creating a new document. You should watch the whole video, it's not that long. I'll still explain that part: You can summon the place command (Top menu: `File > Place`) and then just open up your text file into indesign and you can right away start flowing the text in while creating as many pages as are needed by pressing `shift` key and clicking at the beginning of your document.

Comment: I watched the entire video, I think it had something to do with how I set up my margins and columns, the text was flowing in nicely on the sides, but not on the top and the bottom. After setting my margins richt it now flows in nicely into the newly created pages.

And a total side questions, I've placed a 300dpi image into my document, however in inDesign this is showing up all pixelated, it's fine though when I export it as a PDF for print.

Comment: @woutr_be Hmmn.. You said that you solved it by pasting entire text in one area and then pressing red +. In the video he shows a way that does this in a better way. It brings the styling in with the text. works better on latest versions of indesign. And as far as that image question goes, you can go to (top menu: `View > Overprint preview`) at the top of the list and then images should be showing properly. In some cases images might still show up pixelated, this would be because the linked image is no longer found and (topmenu: `Window > Links`) panel should tell you if there are any missing.

Comment: Yes, at first I solved by just pressing the red+. Then I followed the one form the video as it seems a much better solution and far less work.